# WPF alignment inside StatusBar

Tags: wpf

I want to have Image which in centered inside StatusBar and DockPanel which is align to right in StatusBar

```
<StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30">

    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <Image  />
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock />
            <Controls:ProgressRing />
        </StackPanel>

    </StatusBarItem >

</StatusBar>
```

I have above code unfortunately it's not working , StackPanel is correctly alight to right but Image is alight to left...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StatusBar` uses a `DockPanel` to position the `StatusBarItems` which is not very convenient when you have several items.

To circumvent your issue, you can create your own layout in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, for instance, a 3 columns `Grid`:

Place your image in the center of the middle column, and place your custom control on the right of the 3rd column.

```
<StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30">
     <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition />
                 <ColumnDefinition />
                 <ColumnDefinition />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

     <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image />
     </StatusBarItem>
     <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock />
           <Controls:ProgressRing />
        </StackPanel>
     </StatusBarItem >
  </StatusBar>
```